# GETDATE() in SqlServer 2008 is entering different date time on Server than client

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2

I am inserting the current date time using `GETDATE()` in a procedure in SQL SERVER 2008, but `GETDATE()` is entering different time on server than local server after deploying an application.

I inserted record on `2015-10-28 15.10.07` but on server `GETDATE()` is inserting `2015-10-28 09:37:17.877`, why time difference?

Comment: Maybe the server is in a different time zone? Or the clocks are set different?

Comment: Most likely [GETUTCDATE()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms178635%28v=sql.120%29.aspx) will solve your problem.

Comment: Are you using varchar for dates?

Comment: i am using DATETIME type for date

Answer (score 0):

The dates and time are different as you used the function at two separate times on two separate machines.

`GETDATE()` returns the current database system timestamp as a datetime value without the database time zone offset.

**This value is derived from the operating system of the computer on which the instance of SQL Server is *running***.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your local server and the main server are running on different time zones.

The difference would be removed if you can connect to your main server from your local server and in that particular connection window execute SELECT GETDATE() ..

Hope it helps.